# Django: same Comment model for different Post types

Tags: python, django

In my project, I currently have two different post types (but in the future they could be more): *Posts* and *Reviews*. Both can be commented, so they could share the same *Comment* model.

The problem is: if I create two different apps for Post and Review (and eventually other post types), should I share the same Comment model with a GenericForeignKey or should I recreate in each app the same Comment model with a specific ForeignKey? Or maybe I just should put every post type in a unique common app?

Comment: My recommendation is to just use GenericForeignKey.  That will give you DRY, and you won't run into weird problems that noone else has.

Comment: And where should I place the Comment model?

Comment: You'll place that in a separate app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set it up in one of the following ways.

**Easy solution: use when needed**

Directory (app) structure:

```
post
    models.py
review
    models.py
common
    models.py
```

In `common/models.py`, you then define the comment:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default='')
    ...
```

In `post/models.py`, you then refer to this class whenever you need it:

```
from common.models import Comment

class Post(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='comments')
    ...
```

**Generic solution: mixins**

Another option is to create a *mixin behavior* inside your common app.

```
class Commentable(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='comments')
```

And mix this behavior in by inheriting from it.

```
from common.models import Commentable

class Post(Commentable, models.Model):
    ...
```

You should read a bit about mixins before using them all over the place though.

Comment: Doesn't your easy solution just create a `comment_id` column in the `post` table? How would that work? A post will have many comments right? Shouldn't it be the other way around? You should be referencing `Post` in `Comment` right?

Comment: Good point, you are absolutely right! It makes both the simple and the generic solution less easy to implement, unfortunately, since one needs to specify multiple fields with different `ForeignKey`s on the model `Comment.`

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you can check django-polymorphic.
https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/